# List all custom post type posts from a given category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type `myposttype` and it's taxonomy is called `myposttype_categories`.

`myposttype_categories` have multiple terms inside, such as `foo` and `bar`.

The tricky question is - how do I list all myposttype posts that belong to `foo` (or `bar`)?

I thought this should work, but it does not:

```
$args = array( 
       'post_type' => 'myposttype', 
       'myposttype_categories'=> 'foo');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And the loop is always empty.

I've tried possibly every [Taxonomy paramter for WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) also checked [Category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

There are very old posts addressing the issue issue, but it seems it still doesn't work after 3 years...? Or am I missing something?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-and-custom-taxonomies

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13582

[edit]

That's how I register my post type:

```
add_action('init', 'myposttype_register');  

function myposttype_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Myposttype', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Myposttype item', 'myposttype item'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add Myposttype', 'myposttype item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','comments','trackbacks'),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'myposttype' , $args );

}
```

And taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy("myposttype_categories", array("myposttype"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Type", "rewrite" => true));
```

Comment: what does your code look like that iterates over the results of your query? what does your code look like that registers your post type and taxonomy?

Comment: I've been checking everything from WP_Query to hated query_posts, both taxonomy and custom post types are ok, code that iterates the results also, does filtering custom post types using terms work for you? Because I'm afraid it just simply doesn't and that's the problem. All examples in Codex use 'post' post type...

Comment: your code above works fine for me, that's why I asked about your post type and tax registration code, and what your loop looked like. it is indeed possible to do what you want, you've just got an issue with your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about doing a [`tax_query`](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/)?

```
$args = array( 
       'post_type' => 'myposttype', 
       'tax_query'=> array(
            'taxonomy' => 'myposttype_categories',
            'terms' => array('foo'),
            'field' => 'slug',
        )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($loop);
```

Facepalm question, you are sure that these taxonomies/post types exist and that there are posts filed under them?

**Update**

The query seems to work fine for me, and I am able to show a list of the posts I have added with that term/category.  I moved your `register_taxonomy` call into the function that fires on `init`.  [Per the codex it is inadvisable to call `register_taxonomy` outside of an action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and could be the cause of your troubles.

```
add_action('init', 'myposttype_register');

function myposttype_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Myposttype', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Myposttype item', 'myposttype item'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add Myposttype', 'myposttype item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','comments','trackbacks'),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      );

    register_post_type( 'myposttype' , $args );

    register_taxonomy("myposttype_categories", array("myposttype"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Type", "rewrite" => true));

}
```

And the query:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'myposttype',
'myposttype_categories'=> 'foo');

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p><?php
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();
```

For what its worth, both of the following also work as arguments, though since you are only querying a single taxonomy you probably don't need to use the `tax_query`.  I used that initially because I thought you needed to find posts in both terms.

```
$args = array( 'myposttype_categories'=> 'foo' );
```

and

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'myposttype',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'myposttype_categories',
        'terms' => array('foo'),
        'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Returns empty object for me, are you certain it works? By the way I wanted to display only `foo` or `bar`, not both :) And yeah, my taxonomy exists, there are posts filed under it.

Comment: Yeah, just checked, looks like tax_query works alright only with `post` post type, and for custom post types returns nothing for arrays such as: `'terms' => array('foo'`) or everything for strings: `'terms' => 'foo'`. Well, looks like we still can't mix custom post types AND term filtering? :(

Comment: You said foo (or bar) so I misinterpreted that mean you had items in both categories.  This query is looking for items that are in both, so if you don't have any you would get an empty object.  For what it's worth, `tax_query` will work with any post type.  You should probably post your code for registering the post type and the taxonomies. I'll adjust my code, though if you are doing a simple query, what you posted should work which is why I think you need to post more code.

Comment: PS- I didn't mean to "shout" and bold everything, I forgot that # is markdown for bold. Doh.

Comment: That's alright, just updated my question with custom post type and taxonomy registration codes.

Comment: Dam, you're right, it works, but looks like not in my case. Got any idea what might be breaking it? Taxonomy exists, terms exist, custom post type exists, but still I'm getting no output. And when I use the same code on Twenty Twelve it works like a charm. I even tried to use this code just after the body tag before any potential loops etc. but nothing seems to help :/

Comment: Something is conflicting in your theme I'd guess.  You'll have to dig through the functions.php piece by piece.  Maybe comment everything out and then slowly add each function back in?  That's the worst.